# Get list of extended classes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
classA 
classB extends ClassA
classC extends ClassB
```

I created object on classC:

```
var myClassC= new classC();
```

ClassA has this method:

```
public get className(): string {
    var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
    var results = (funcNameRegex).exec(this["constructor"].toString());
    return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
}
```

Which returns "ClassC" string if I call myClassC.getClassName();

What I need is to get a list of all classes up to the base class: ClassC, ClassB, ClassA. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that is indeed possible:

```
function getClassName(obj: any): string {
    var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
    var results = (funcNameRegex).exec(obj.constructor.toString());
    return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
}

class ClassA {
    public get className(): string[] {
        let classNames = [];
        let obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
        let className: string;

        while ((className = getClassName(obj)) !== "Object") {
            classNames.push(className);
            obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        }

        return classNames;
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {}

class ClassC extends ClassB {}

let a = new ClassA();
console.log(a.className); // ["ClassA"]

let b = new ClassB();
console.log(b.className); // ["ClassB", "ClassA"]

let c = new ClassC();
console.log(c.className); // ["ClassC", "ClassB", "ClassA"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getClassName(obj%3A%20any)%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%09var%20funcNameRegex%20%3D%20%2Ffunction%20(.%7B1%2C%7D)%5C(%2F%3B%0A%09var%20results%20%3D%20(funcNameRegex).exec(obj.constructor.toString())%3B%0A%09return%20(results%20%26%26%20results.length%20%3E%201)%20%3F%20results%5B1%5D%20%3A%20%22%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ClassA%20%7B%0A%09public%20get%20className()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20classNames%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%09let%20obj%20%3D%20Object.getPrototypeOf(this)%3B%0A%09%09let%20className%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09while%20((className%20%3D%20getClassName(obj))%20!%3D%3D%20%22Object%22)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09classNames.push(className)%3B%0A%09%09%09obj%20%3D%20Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%09return%20classNames%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ClassB%20extends%20ClassA%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20ClassC%20extends%20ClassB%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20ClassA()%3B%0Aconsole.log(a.className)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22ClassA%22%5D%0A%0Alet%20b%20%3D%20new%20ClassB()%3B%0Aconsole.log(b.className)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22ClassB%22%2C%20%22ClassA%22%5D%0A%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20new%20ClassC()%3B%0Aconsole.log(c.className)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22ClassC%22%2C%20%22ClassB%22%2C%20%22ClassA%22%5D))

Comment: not working now and prints empty strings in an array